# SQL - SSMS - Working script no longer working

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am training up on a bit of `SQL` and yesterday thought that I got the general idea of it. My script yesterday was completely working and returning the data I asked for when I asked for it - I reloaded the script today and for some reason the following error message is showing up.

> "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.DoubleClick_Floodlight'."

I have a colleague who is also training with me and despite us having to 2 same `scripts` my one won't load and hers will - She also emailed me over her script so I could copy and paste it in and implement i on my computer but still no luck.

I have also tried dragging over the table name into my script to ensure it matches but the following error is still presented - I've attached screenshots of the script..

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: I guess that db object doesnt exist. Are you sure that same db object is referred in that script. Check in the db schema for that object

Comment: Does the table `dbo.DoubleClick_Floodlight` definitely exist in your database? Are you connecting to the same database?

Comment: have you actually selected the correct database to run this against? my guess is that the database at the top of your SSMS window is 'master' which would explain why the table doesn't exist on this database

Comment: Issue a `USE the_database_that_contains_that_table` command. Happens to me all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem will be one of:

1. you are connected to the wrong database (see the database drop down in the top left hand corner of SSMS). Check that it matches the database you are expecting to connect to. (Ctrl+U will take you to this drop down).
2. the object no longer exists within the database. If the above is correct, have a look in the Object explorer to see if you can still see the object there - again check that you're looking under the correct database in the tree.
3. you no longer have permissions on the object.